# Derivative of singular integrand

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to differentiate this integral with respect to $x$:
$$T(x,t) = {1\over\sqrt\pi} \int_0^t {g(s) \over \sqrt{t-s} } e^{-{x^2\over 4(t-s)}} ds$$
According to this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/0122035) the derivative with respect to $x$ at $x=0$ is
$T_x(0,t) = g(t)$. (The equation in the paper has extra terms, which I've simplified here.)
However, if I pull the derivative through the integral
$$
\partial_x T(x,t) =
{1\over\sqrt\pi} \int_0^t {g(s) \over \sqrt{t-s} }
  e^{-{x^2\over 4(t-s)}} {-x\over 2(t-s)}  ds
$$
which would be zero at $x=0$. I suspect one cannot exchange the derivative with the integral here because of the singular integrand. So **how do I verify that** $T_x(0,t) = g(t)$?
I should add that all variables are real and $g$ is well-behaved (continuous and bounded).

Comment: $T(x,t)$ is even over $x$, which enforces $\partial_xT(x,t)\Big|_{x=0}=0$. Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: Good point @MostafaAyaz! The equation really is stated that way in the paper. They cite another paper for it, but I can't find the equation there in this form. So maybe it's an error of some sort.